# Could not select 'OK' in mysql-apt-config [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, config, ubuntu-14.04, apt

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. `sudo apt-get update` always give me this option to configure mysql-apt-config.

[image]

I am have tried to select the version, press 'tab' -> key highlighted on 'OK', press 'Enter' but nothing happens. It goes back again highlighting the version number.

Software Updater also crashes at mysql-apt-config.

Any idea on what is causing this problem and how to get rid of it? Thx.

Comment: Seems like some install / configuration keeps failing. Why have you installed `mysql-apt-config`, and is `purging`  it an option?

Comment: @Wrikken This started happening after I tried to update my MySql Workbench to 6.2.4 by downloading the .deb package from their website. It crashed my Ubuntu software center and thereafter it is blocking other updates.

Comment: So, if you're not using it.. `apt-get purge mysql-apt-config`?

Comment: Thx. It worked. I used sudo apt-get purge mysql-apt-config to purge problematic package and updated my Workbench again. Now, it is in the latest version.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When you can't do

```
apt-get purge mysql-apt-config
```

because you're trapped: It won't execute because dpkg is interrupted, and "sudo dpkg --configure -a" backs you to the broken "configuring mysql-apt-config" screen...

edit:  `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-apt-config.postinst`

add `exit` at the beginning , then get rid of the package :

```
sudo dpkg --configure mysql-apt-config

sudo apt-get remove mysql-apt-config
```

Comment: Finally! Thanks a lot, I was trapped like you said and after I followed your method I could reinstall using [Amadu Bah's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1263890/amadu-bah).

Answer (score 3):

- Unistall current packages

  1. $ `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`
  2. $ `sudo apt-get autoremove`
  3. $ `sudo apt-get autoclean`
- Install dependency: `sudo apt-get install libaio1`
- Download the currect `mysql-apt-config<version>.deb` for your installation from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/.
- Install into your system: sudo dpkg -i `mysql-apt-config<version>.deb`
- Instal mysql server: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the CUI (character user interface):

- highlight the version you want (using arrow keys)
- press 'Enter'

This should take you back to the list of packages (i.e. not the list of version numbers). Then:

- highlight 'Apply' (using arrow keys)
- press 'Enter'