# Could not select 'OK' in mysql-apt-config [Ubuntu 14.04]. Purging not working

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, config, apt

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (Mint)

sudo dpkg --configure -a' takes me to the package configuration of the mysql-apt-config. However, when I select the server version that I wish to receive (mysql-5.6) the terminal does not respond when I click enter in . I tried purging with 'sudo apt-get purge mysql-apt-config' as addressed in a previous question: [Could not select 'OK' in mysql-apt-config [Ubuntu 14.04]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154067/could-not-select-ok-in-mysql-apt-config-ubuntu-14-04). However this returns me to: E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Not sure how to move on from this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I don't know whether you already found the answer or not, but since this is the first link I got from google about the same problem I found today (after upgrading to 14.04.2), and there is no one that answering this question, so here is how I solve the problem, just in case somebody else is questioning it.

I remove the mysql-apt-config using the dpkg, not using the apt.
Here is how it's done

> sudo dpkg --purge mysql-apt-config

Hope that's helped someone else :D

Comment: Spent ages trying to fix this. Very helpful, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Seems no-one at ORacle or Linux Mint is awake